# GraphQL Scraping Reviews into a Table Format using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, graphql

I am trying to scrape reviews from random M&S website for random products. I copied the graphql URL and got reviews of first 20 where i cannot increase the limit to more than 20.
**What I am looking for in here:

1. Is there any way to get all reviews at once from website, as for some products it may have more than 1000 reviews posted.
2. How to convert this JSON format to a table.**

Thanks

```
import json
import requests

query = """
query GetReviewsV2($id: String!, $sortBy: ReviewsSortBy!, $sortOrder: ReviewsSortOrder!, $limit: PositiveInt!, $offset: NonNegativeInt!, $filter: ReviewsFilter) {
  reviewsByProductId(
    filterAndSortInput: {sortBy: $sortBy, sortOrder: $sortOrder, filter: $filter}
    id: $id
    locale: GB
    paginationInput: {limit: $limit, offset: $offset}
  ) {
    ... on ReviewsSuccessResponse {
      __typename
      stats {
        __typename
        averageOverallRating
        totalReviewCount
        secondaryRatingsAverages {
          averageRating
          id
          __typename
        }
        ratingDistribution {
          ratingValue
          count
          __typename
        }
      }
      controls {
        itemsPerPage
        resultsFromIndex
        totalItems
        __typename
      }
      reviews {
        id
        isRecommended
        helpfulness
        secondaryRatings {
          valueLabel
          maxLabel
          label
          id
          value
          displayType
          __typename
        }
        userNickname
        title
        submissionTime
        positiveFeedbackCount
        negativeFeedbackCount
        isRatingsOnly
        rating
        reviewText
        clientResponses {
          response
          department
          date
          name
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
    }
    __typename
  }
}
"""
json_data = {
    'query': query,
    'variables': {
        'id': 'P60585886', 'sortBy': 'SUBMISSION_TIME', 'sortOrder': 'DESC', 'limit': 20, 'offset': 20,
    },
    'operationName': 'GetReviewsV2',
}

response = requests.post('https://prod.prod.gql-mesh.gql.mnscorp.net/graphql', json=json_data)
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```

Here is the code i used to get reviews in Python.

And here is the response i received:

```
{
  "data": {
    "reviewsByProductId": {
      "__typename": "ReviewsSuccessResponse",
      "stats": {
        "__typename": "ReviewsStats",
        "averageOverallRating": 4.349754,
        "totalReviewCount": 203,
        "secondaryRatingsAverages": [
          {
            "averageRating": 4.449367088607595,
            "id": "Quality",
            "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatingsAverages"
          },
          {
            "averageRating": 4.278787878787878,
            "id": "Value",
            "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatingsAverages"
          }
        ],
        "ratingDistribution": [
          {
            "ratingValue": 5,
            "count": 147,
            "__typename": "ReviewsRatingDistribution"
          },
          {
            "ratingValue": 4,
            "count": 20,
            "__typename": "ReviewsRatingDistribution"
          },
          {
            "ratingValue": 1,
            "count": 17,
            "__typename": "ReviewsRatingDistribution"
          },
          {
            "ratingValue": 3,
            "count": 13,
            "__typename": "ReviewsRatingDistribution"
          },
          {
            "ratingValue": 2,
            "count": 6,
            "__typename": "ReviewsRatingDistribution"
          }
        ]
      },
      "controls": {
        "itemsPerPage": 20,
        "resultsFromIndex": 20,
        "totalItems": 203,
        "__typename": "ReviewsControls"
      },
      "reviews": [
        {
          "id": "156458930",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": null,
          "title": "Excellent Service",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-28T12:22:51.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Excellent service from M & S and their Customer Service operative in Cape Town, South Africa.  A thoroughly reassuring and enjoyable experience, which the recipient of the gift confirmed once received.  Proving to me that one should go to M & S first and foremost, every time!",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156418772",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 1,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 1,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Beverley Taylor",
          "title": "Disappointed to say the least",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-26T16:39:29.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 1,
          "reviewText": "Ordered for Easter as a gift & arrived 10 days late!",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156413609",
          "isRecommended": false,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 4,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 3,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "mincey",
          "title": "Lovely bag",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-26T13:08:05.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 4,
          "reviewText": "Very short dated products only two days on 2 cakes",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156375345",
          "isRecommended": false,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 3,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Aunty 18",
          "title": "Afternoon tea gift bag",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-24T21:56:33.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 1,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 3,
          "reviewText": "The picture shows a lovely Victoria sponge. There was no Victoria sponge included in the gift sent to my niece for her special birthday.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156344689",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Elderslie1963",
          "title": "Great for a gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-23T16:01:39.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 3,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Lovely gift and the Victoria sponge is delicious. Well thought contents and lovely packaging.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156338832",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 3,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 1,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Manash27",
          "title": "Afternoon tea gift bag",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-23T11:34:34.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 1,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 3,
          "reviewText": "Beautiful bag \r\nCake dates were very short two days only \r\nNobody could eat all that in two days\r\nSo alot of waste",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156338766",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": 0.33333298563957214,
          "secondaryRatings": [],
          "userNickname": "Fruend",
          "title": "Very welcome gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-23T11:29:28.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 1,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 2,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Did not see it myself but it was well received by my friends",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156301992",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [],
          "userNickname": "Cathy Cameron",
          "title": "Afternoon Tea",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-21T15:00:38.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Excellent service, lovely yummy products!   All came in a lovely reusable bag!",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156253460",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "crescentmoon4",
          "title": "Great vslue gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-19T14:26:32.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 3,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "I gave this as a gift and the recipient was delighted with it. It\u2019s good quality items at a good price and a useful shopping bag as well. A good value gift",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156253112",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 4,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Nice cup of tea",
          "title": "Lovely afternoon tea",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-19T14:15:05.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 1,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "I really liked this little afternoon tea, the best before dates on the cakes were good, and the shopping bag is very nice too.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156192310",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Malbec2020",
          "title": "Afternoon tea gift bag",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-17T11:21:16.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "My friend was thrilled with this gift for her 90th birthday I will definitely order again",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156192246",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "CMKee",
          "title": "Good value for money",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-17T11:18:49.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Bought as a gift and my family were delighted with it.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156182010",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Wear Jeans",
          "title": "Mothering Sunday",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-16T21:24:13.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Sent as a Mother\u2019s Day gift. Mother in law (and Father in law) delighted.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156129283",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "principle",
          "title": "Afternoon Tea",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-14T13:54:26.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 2,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "I sent 2 afternoon teas one to a friend and one to my daughter they both said how good they were and what a lovely selection of goodies were  included.\nMy friends was delivered on time to the correct address.  However the one to my daughter was delivered to the wrong address to that on the order and she had to chase round looking for it. Had I not told her she would get a surprise from M & S on the Wednesday she would not have known there was anything arriving as it was she did not get it and had to chase around for it . The wrong postcode was put in by M&S",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156088266",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "NMA229",
          "title": "Gorgeous gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-12T17:23:43.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Gorgeous gift, the recipient absolutely loved it. Will definitely buy again.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156081005",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Gingerdelight",
          "title": "A nice gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-12T11:54:52.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Bought as a birthday gift, I didn\u2019t actually see this product, but the recipients were delighted with it.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156063041",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [],
          "userNickname": "DebbMc",
          "title": "Awesome gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-11T15:33:58.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Was bought as a gift, and was very impressed with all treats and even the gift bag.",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156042923",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "AnnieTCG",
          "title": "Perfect treat",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-10T18:37:55.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 1,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "I sent this to my Mum when she was in hospital. She absolutely loved it, particularly the Victoria Sponge and shared it with the nurses and the other ladies in her bay. It was beautifully presented the bag and the beautiful tin of posh teabags are so pretty. Thank you Marks  and Spencer!",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "156037194",
          "isRecommended": true,
          "helpfulness": null,
          "secondaryRatings": [
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Quality",
              "id": "Quality",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            },
            {
              "valueLabel": null,
              "maxLabel": null,
              "label": "Value for Money",
              "id": "Value",
              "value": 5,
              "displayType": "NORMAL",
              "__typename": "ReviewsSecondaryRatings"
            }
          ],
          "userNickname": "Annval",
          "title": "Gift",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-10T14:14:08.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 0,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 4,
          "reviewText": "Sent as a gift with other things . Recipient very pleased with it . Nicely presented and even bag was good quality . Disappointing though that the flowers could not be delivered at the same time",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        },
        {
          "id": "155970721",
          "isRecommended": null,
          "helpfulness": 1,
          "secondaryRatings": [],
          "userNickname": "Berlin Breakfast",
          "title": "Very pleased",
          "submissionTime": "2023-04-07T13:22:07.000+00:00",
          "positiveFeedbackCount": 2,
          "negativeFeedbackCount": 0,
          "isRatingsOnly": false,
          "rating": 5,
          "reviewText": "Good selection and lovely bag too! Very pleased and would recommend, enough for more than just one afternoon tea!",
          "clientResponses": [],
          "__typename": "ReviewsReview"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need all reviews to get at once instead of getting 20 reviews. And to convert this JSON format to a table like format.

Comment: could you try scraping for another `id`? cos generally if you increase the limit it should work

Comment: Hi Kulasangar, I tried for few products but couldn't do for more than 20 at a time. Just wondering if any other way could help.

Comment: Your response will likely contain paging metadata such as the next offset to use. Can you provide an abbreviated copy of the response. Failing that you would just loop through the results a bunch of times setting `limit` and `offset` as appropriate presumably until you no longer got results.

Comment: @JonSG Hi, Is that the response you are asking for. I just added the response in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, check out `controls`. It tells you how many results there are, how many results per page of data and the current offset. You need to specify a "next" query using resultsFromIndex and itemsPerPage to set the $offset for the next page of data

Comment: @JonSG I am a bit new to Python and Scraping. Could you please give an example or link for similar type of problem for creating next page or query. It would be really helpful. Thanks once again.